# Anaconda doesnt launch since PyQt5

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, anaconda, spyder

I'm truly desperated...

Yesterday I installed PyQt5 to start working on spyder... but today when I wanted to start working again... spyder didn't open... then i tried to open anaconda with no sucess... I'd tried every "solution" I found on google to solve the problem without any sucess...

Can you help me throught the process?

I actually don't know that much about comands, I'm a begginer, I hope someone could help to fix this

I have tried to unistall the packege, re-install it, i update the conda... I uninstalled also anaconda and re-installed

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem with my Anaconda Navigator not starting.  Finally traced the problem to pyqt5.  Of which I had version 5.15.9.  I uninstalled it entirely by putting this  in the Anaconda Powershell Prompt:

```
pip uninstall pyqt5
```

That got Anaconda Navigator running again for me.  Tho it's not  really a happy ending for me because I tried all the available prior versions and they broke Anaconda-Navigator. I like Jupyter Lab so I guess I'll have to open it direct or something if I want to use pyqt5.

BUT for YOU installing a prior version should work because when I run the tests it showed me a warning that Spyder doesn't work unless you're using the lowest version.  So try this code and see if it works:

```
pip install --upgrade pyqt5==5.12.3 --user
```

Well I hope that works for you.  Good luck!